# Pm2 process restarting each 8 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, typescript, pm2

I have a program developed in typescript, a function is executed each hour (I have try to execute it each 5, 10 min) and that is defined in index.ts that I execute with pm2 start "npm start". In the index I define that the first time the function is executed it should do one thing and then in all the next executions it do another one, I can see when one or another task is done because I print a flag in the logger.
So the problem is that I have seen in multiple proofs that the first execution is being done each exactly 8 hours.

````
[2022-04-29T17:15:22.363] [INFO] app - Value: true
[2022-04-30T01:15:26.236] [INFO] app - Value: true
[2022-04-30T09:15:29.455] [INFO] app - Value: true
[2022-04-30T17:15:32.996] [INFO] app - Value: true
[2022-05-01T01:15:36.521] [INFO] app - Value: true```

any idea of what is appening?
````

Comment: What do pm2's logfiles say about this?

Comment: If process restart you can verify that with ``pm2 list`` It will show you the uptime of you process and the restart number.

Comment: For more help, please provide error logs and source code.